# Adding a value to a dynamic form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to pull the contents of some input text boxes into a database. The first box is displayed but I'm using this Javascript to create some of them dynamically:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter !== limit)  {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = " <input type='text' name='myInputs[]' size=40>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

How can I add a value to the form which will be different for each box created so I can reference them in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you want. All your input fields will be accessible via the `$_POST['myInputs']` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: scratch that, I've never tried using an array to group inputs, but it works so use that instead. Keep the name of your inputs as myInputs[] but reference in php like this:

```
$_POST[myInputs][0]
```

for your first field and

```
$_POST[myInputs][1]
```

for the second etc..

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, that works well. I was trying something along the same lines but I'm unfamiliar with Javascript syntax. How would I express counter+1 so it'd start with 2?

Comment: why do you want to start at 2?

Comment: because the first box is already there and the javascript caters for the boxes that are added. so the first one added would be t2.

Comment: ah, in that case the above will still work, so long as all the inputs have the attribute name='myInputs[]'

Answer (score 0):

```
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>//use jQuery. it makes life easy.
            <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){//fire when the page is ready
                    $('.addFields').click(function(){//any time someone clicks on a element with the class addFields
                        if( $('.myInputs').length < 10 ){ // if there are less than 10 input fields...
                            $($(this).attr('rel')).append("<br/><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' class='myInputs' size='40' id='myInputs"+($('.myInputs').length)+"'>");
                            // add another input field with an ID equal to it's place in line.
                                }
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </head>
        <body >
            <a rel="#addToMe" class="addFields" href="#">Add a field</a><!-- the triggering element this can be anything that can be clicked on-->
            <div id="addToMe"><!-- the element holding our input fields, new ones get added to the back of here, note that the trigger's rel attribute is the ID of this attribute and started with a "#' ID identifier-->
                <input type='text' name='myInputs[]' class='myInputs' size='40' id='myInputs0'>
            </div>

        </body>
```